# Allure First Steps - Failing POM.XML

Tags: allure

trying to use the Allure framework - but having some issues.

I am using Maven, Junit and Eclipse.  Created a very simple test case and confirmed all this works.  So next step was to add in Allure.  Now it seems that when I add in the allure dependency, everything goes wrong (all subsequent dependancies fail, and the POM which worked, now has 50+ errors.)

If I remove the following, then I can launch mvn clean test and my test case runs (Eclipse also realises something is wrong and gives me an error)

I figure it's got to be something really obvious, but I've been staring at it so long I can't see it.

Not sure how to attach the POM, but I think the error is in these sections.

```
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <compiler.version>1.7</compiler.version>
   <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
   <allure.version>{latest-allure-version}</allure.version>    
 </properties>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
    <version>${allure.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Ok I think that part of my problem is I am taking the sample code too literally - I've now got a copy of the Allure junit4 example and it seems they specify the allure.version (as 1.4.3). So my plan is to take their example - which doesn't use any selenium like opening a browser, etc  - and add pieces in to see how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sorted - seems that I had a dependancy issue when I added in Selenium.